# Interaction Between Flutter and FastAPI

Tags: flutter, rest, fastapi, python-3.8

Ubuntu 20.04LTS, with Python 3.8 for FastAPI, and Flutter 2.8.1, with Android SDK version 32.0.0.

I am trying to send a Map from Flutter to FastAPI.
I have figured out how to POST, but how can I receive it from FastAPI side?

Is database necessary?

Flutter side:

```
import 'src/models/keywords_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get, post;
import 'dart:convert';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen(List<KeywordsModel> keywords, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}


class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> keywords = [];
  final Map<String, dynamic> keywordsMap = {};

  
  Future<void> postKeywords(parsedJson) async {
    await post(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:8000", "/search"), body: parsedJson);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          print('---------------' * 20);
          for (int i = 0 ; i < keywords.length ; i++) {
            keywordsMap["$i"] = keywords[i];
          }
          var parsedJson = json.encode(keywordsMap);
          postKeywords(parsedJson);
        },
      ),

/// Skipped many lines

    );
  }
}
```

FastAPI side:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import json


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/search/")
async def receive_keywords():
    """What to Put Here?"""
    json.loads(?????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Resonse or JsonResponse. you have to define a dict or map and then send it by wrapping in one of the above.
Here is the link in case you want to read more.
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna using flutter as the frontend, I really recommend you to use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) and retrofit to handle the API integration. And those two packages would help you easily manage and handle all your API endpoints.
Take the below image as an example [image]. You need to write the python as like:

```py
@app.post("/merchant/change/password")
async def receive_keywords(
    confirmPassword: str = Query(None, alias='confirmPassword')
    merchantId: int = Query(None, alias='merchantId')
    newPassword: str = Query(None, alias='newPassword')
    oldPassword: str = Query(None, alias='oldPassword')
    session: str = Query(None, alias='session')
):
    return True
```

Comment: [chopper](https://pub.dev/packages/chopper) is also viable!

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON response without data, but you can add data you can change "Pong" for var. (This works to .post())

```
@_app.get("/")
def read_root():
    """Root route"""
    return {"Ping": "Pong"}
```

other example:

```
    response = {"limit": limit, "offset": offset, "data": users}
```